# HTML center content through margin auto not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following Html code

```
<div id="team">
    <h1>Team</h1>
    <img src="assets/divider.png" id="divider">
    <img src="assets/team.png" id="team_pic">
</div>
```

The following CSS

```
div#team {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    right:auto;
    left:auto;
}
```

However, the child elements divider and team pic are all the way to the left. I though margin:auto would center everything.

then I put the following into the child elements.

```
div#team img#team_pic {
    width:704px;
    height:462px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

Nope, nothing happen, the elements still to left and not centered.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set a width to #team, for example:

```
div#team {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 800px;
}
```

... which is a shorthand version of:

```
div#team {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Images are inline level elements by default. You need to use `display:block;` if you want your images and margin to work properly.

```
img{
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Team needs to have a width to be able to use margin: auto.

```
div#team {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/JHyVn/)

Answer (score 2):

float will upset this too..  `float:none;` does the trick if you think it may be inheriting a 'float' directive from another rule somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
#team { 
    margin: auto; 
    width: 400px;
}
```

Basically **margin depends on width if and only if** we want to show our div in the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

****Use the 
display:block; 
for the images classes.****

Answer (score 0):

If you donot want to give fixed width then we can go for width: max-content;

```css
#team {
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can trip you up is if you have any neighboring `display: flex` tags.

Sometimes only one sibling will have `flex-grow: 1` set and it will eat up all the width so margins have no room to auto grow.

To fix this make sure both siblings grow at the same rate. They should have the same flex-grow if you want to center both with margins.