# Margin 0 auto not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have this following code in ASP.net but its simple HTML here

```
<div id="site_content">

    <div style="margin:0 auto;" class="middle">

    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Search" />

    </div>
</div>
```

**I want the middle div with *class="middle"*  to be in center of the page.
Why it is not working?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML center content through margin auto not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692302/html-center-content-through-margin-auto-not-working)

Comment: To your style property of the inner div, or to your css class of middle add "text-align: center;" and it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `div` is in the center of the page, it's just that the width of the `div` is the same of the page.

If you set a width on the `div`, centering it will have an effect. Example:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width: 200px" class="middle">
```

Comment: Just an addition. That is due to the `display` property. A div element is `display:block` by default. This property fills it's container in width. You could also make it work, even if not setting a specific width, if you changed the property for something else, like: `display: table;`

Comment: @LcSalazar: Well, it's not only that. The default width for a `div` is `auto`, which means that it uses the full width of the parent element.

Comment: Thank You ;) Guffa and LcSalazar.